# Why aren't there Dimension and Point interfaces?

Tags: java, interfaces

I mean something along the lines of:

```
public interface Dimensioned {
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();
}
```

and

```
public interface Positioned {
    int getX();
    int getY();
}
```

There are a **lot** of standard java classes that have exactly those methods-- notably `Component` and all of its subclasses as well as `Dimension` and `Point`. `Image` could implement `Dimensioned`.
Despite the widespread use of these methods, there's no uniform way of referring to them. Is this a conscious decision on the part of the language designers? In writing this question, I've noticed that it *is* rather difficult to come up with good descriptive names for the interfaces. Even so, it feels like it would be useful to have them. I can't seem to find much information on the topic.

Comment: If you're already subclassing `Point`, why would you need an additional interface?

Comment: But what about multidimensional applications? Two may not be enough. :-)

Comment: And what about `Point`s that have floating point values? (Indeed, OpenCV has a generic Point class that can be specialized for all dimensions and value types.)

Answer (score 8):

Interfaces aren't just some means to group classes together that happen to have common function names, they must have some value to the code that *calls* the functions.  You would need a compelling use case for having something like a `Vector<Dimensioned>` and calling `getWidth()` on all of its elements, whether they're components or something else.  It's easy to come up with use cases for a `Vector<Component>` or a `Vector<Image>`, but not a mixed bag of both.  Feeling "like it would be useful" isn't a compelling reason.

Comment: Perhaps not for `Dimensioned`, but what about an interface that included `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` as well? With that, you would be able to write resizing algorithms independent of class.

Comment: @KyleBuzsaki: `Component` already has a `setSize` function.  For example, if you're working with Swing, you can already just pass around `Vector<Component>`.  If you're working with your own graphical primitives, they probably either inherit from `Component`, or are sufficiently different from `Component` that sharing an interface with `Component` is of low value.